# Identifying best photos from a photo collection

Tags: powershell

I borrowed code from [this website](http://www.phoscript.com/publish/home) and it looks helpful to me as a photographer. Since I do not know PowerShell I would like to ask if this code looks OK. I do not want to lose my photos by mistake.

```cs
$source_to_use_as_reference = "C:\photos\mytrip_to_hawai\Best\"
$destination_to_copy =        "C:\photos\mytrip_to_hawai\Best\Best_CR2\"
$location_to_find_CR2_files = "C:\photos\mytrip_to_hawai\CR2\"
# these are the codes to find CR2 files that matches with JPG files and copy
# them to new destination
cls
$count_all = 0 
$count_matches = 0 
$a = Get-ChildItem -Path $source_to_use_as_reference -Recurse -File
foreach ($item in $a) {
    $count_all += 1
    if ($item.Name -match "JPG") {
        $name_as_CR2 = $item.Name.Replace('JPG','CR2')
        $location_and_cr2_name = $location_to_find_CR2_files + $name_as_CR2
        if (Test-Path -Path $location_and_cr2_name ) {
            $destination_and_CR2_name = $destination_to_copy + $name_as_CR2
            if (Test-Path -Path  $destination_and_CR2_name) {
                Write-Output "already exists I skipped ... "   $destination_and_CR2_name 
            } else {
                $count_matches += 1
                Write-Host "I found it "  $destination_and_CR2_name
                Copy-Item -Path $location_and_cr2_name -Destination $destination_to_copy
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
}
Write-Output "$count_matches matches found and files copied to destination $destination_to_copy"
```

Comment: Why not test it out with some sample images and sample folders? No need to test against your real photos.

Comment: It won't erase anything.The only commands used are Test-Path / Get-ChildItem and Copy-Item. No remove or anything like that. 

As said above though, in doubts, test on a sample batch or make a copy of your original folder before starting in case. 

That being said, the code above does not do any write or delete operations other than the `Copy-Item`

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing sinister in that script, it simply identifies, counts and **copies** JPGs and CR2 files to a 2nd location.